# Get underlying linq query for FirstOrDefault with Entity Framework 5 (Code First)

Tags: linq, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I can log the underlying query of a linq query by simply using the ToString() method.

```
string raw = query.Where(..whatever..).ToString();
```

I need the exact underlying query for the FirstOrDefault() method

```
query.FirstOrDefault().ToString()
```

because we get a very bad performance for this query and we want to analyze it.
Here the ToString() method only returns the class name.

Is there a possibility to get the underlying query?

Comment: Have you considered using an sql profiler?

Comment: Yes that's the way we do it now, but I would prefer to log it from code.

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

Comment: @Marthijn Yes, I know, but this is only a option for EF 6. We are using EF 5.

Comment: In that case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx

Comment: @Marthijn Written in the answers comment: "You won't get SQL for queries ending with .Single(), .Count(), .Any(), etc. that way"

Comment: @StefanG too bad, didn't know